# PyCharm + cProfile + py.test --> pstat snapshot view + call graph are empty

Tags: python, pycharm, pytest, cprofile

In PyCharm, I set up `py.test` as the default test runner.

I have a simple test case:

```
import unittest
import time

def my_function():
   time.sleep(0.42)

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_something(self):
        my_function()
```

Now I run the test by right-clicking the file and choosing `Profile 'py.test in test_profile.py'`.

I see the test running successfully in the console (it says `collected 1 items`). However, the `Statistics/Call Graph` view showing the generated pstat file is empty and says `Nothing to show`.

I would expect to see profiling information for the `test_something` and `my_function`. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit 1**:
If I change the name of the file to something which does *not* start with `test_`, remove the `unittest.TestCase` and insert a `__main__` method calling `my_function`, I can finally run cProfile without py.test and I see results.

However, I am working on a large project with tons of tests. I would like to directly profile these tests instead of writing extra profiling scripts. Is there a way to call the `py.test` test-discovery module so I can retrieve all tests of the project recursively? (the `unittest` discovery will not suffice since we yield a lot of parametrized tests in generator functions which are not recognized by `unittest`). This way I could at least solve the problem with only 1 additional script.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a work-around. Create an additional python script with the following contents (adapt the path to the tests-root accordingly):

```
import os
import pytest

if __name__ == '__main__':
    source_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    test_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(source_dir, "../"))
    pytest.main(test_dir, "setup.cfg")
```

The script filename must not start with `test_`, else pycharm will force you to run it with `py.test`. Then right-click the file and run it with `Profile`.

This also comes in handy for running it with `Coverage`.

Comment: `test_dir = os.path.dirname(source_dir)` should work here